# Проблема с шейдером в юнити

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Консоль пишет: **"Shader error in 'ShaderFog': Parse error: syntax error, unexpected TOK_PASS, expecting TOK_SETTEXTURE or '}' at line 26"**

Код:

```
Shader "Custom/ShaderFog"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0

        _FogStart("Fog Start", float) = 0 //объявляем наши новые переменные для тумана
        _FogEnd ("Fog End", float) = 50
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200
               
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            half _FogStart;  //определяем новые переменные в рамках CGPROGRAM
            half _FogEnd; 
            
            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
                half fog : TEXCOORD2;  //добавляем новую переменную для расчета расстояния отображения тумана и последующей передачи в fragment функцию
                float4 color : COLOR;
                half3 viewDir : TEXCOORD3;
            };
            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.color = v.color;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

                o.uv.xy = v.uv.xy * unity_LightmapST.xy + unity_LightmapST.zw;
                //fog высчитываем положение тумана в зависимости от заданных значений
                half fogz = UnityObjectToViewPos(v.vertex).z;
                o.fog = saturate((fogz + _FogStart) / (_FogStart - _FogEnd));
                float3 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
                o.viewDir = -(normalize(UnityWorldSpaceViewDir(worldPos)));
                return o;
            }
        

            #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows


            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            struct Input
            {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
            };

            half _Glossiness;
            half _Metallic;
            fixed4 _Color;

            
            UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
               
            UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
            {

                fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;

                o.Metallic = _Metallic;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
            }   

            half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                UNITY_SETUP_STEREO_EYE_INDEX_POST_VERTEX(i);
                fixed4 c = i.color * 0.5;

                #ifdef LIGHTMAP_ON
                  fixed4 lm = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2D(unity_Lightmap, i.uv.xy);
                c.rgb *= lm.rgb * 4;
                #endif
                //fog заменяем плавно цвет поверхности на цвет кубомапы (он же наш туман). Кубомапу нужно задать в настройках освещение (Lighting > Scene > Environment Reflection > Source = Custom > Cubemap = Ваша кубомапа)
                half4 fogCube = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE(unity_SpecCube0, i.viewDir);
                return lerp(c, fogCube, i.fog);
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }   
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

До этого я не использовал шейдеры, так что не знаю как это решить

Пример кода я нашел на сайте:https://pikabu.ru/story/krasivyiy_tuman_v_unity3d_s_vyisokoy_optimizatsiey_6042037#comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитал документацию и узнал, что "#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadow" не используется в "Pass{}"